# What is jQuery18007779947370290756

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery in my page, when I use Chrome developer tool, I found jQuery18007779947370290756 and jQuery object in Console. jQuery18007779947370290756 only contains a few methods. jQuery contains a lot more methods. so what is jQuery18007779947370290756 ? I do not have the url of the page, since it is internal page. the lib I include is just jquery-1.8.0.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.23 and
no JSONP calls.

It looks like if I added a global event `'beforeunload'` to window object. and it is stored in window[expando]. However if I added some events to other DOM object such as `button`, and they are stored in jQuery.cache.
here is the screen shot form jQuery.cache and window[jQuery1800xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]
I am not sure why the guid for that 2 click events are both 8. those 2 click events are binded to 2 buttons. and click event handler are the same function.

[image]

Comment: I always knew Skynet would strike through JQuery.... but in seriousness upvote! I do not know.

Comment: I don't know, but at least it's toll free.

Comment: It's a phone number followed by a SSN.  How odd.

Comment: what's the URL of your page? which libraries are you including?

Comment: what are the methods of the doppelherz jQuery?

Comment: @djjeck      question is edited. the page is internal page, the lib I include is just jquery-1.8.0.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.23

Comment: Interested parties may turn their JS consoles to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page, which has a similar object. (It looks like the number is randomly generated each time.)

Comment: Are there any JSONP requests on your page?

Comment: I usually see this when there's an ajax request occurring on the page. It uses that to return the information somehow.

Comment: Note that this is probably *not* an anonymous JSONP success callback, as I suspected it might be, because 1) anonymous JSONP callbacks are longer and contain an underscore, and 2) JSONP callbacks are made `undefined` as soon as the call is complete.

Comment: @apsillers: Well, so much for my theory :-P

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my FORM element have a random JQuery attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150592/why-does-my-form-element-have-a-random-jquery-attribute)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery adds this property to elements when you store data on them. As this property is on the `window` element, somewhere in your code you're doing something equivalent to:

```
$(window).data('something', 1);
```

Note that jQuery events also uses the `data` module behind the scenes, so this could also be because you're adding an event to the `window` object.

For normal nodes (i.e. elements with a `nodeType` property), this value is [set to a GUID](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ab409d14bc6db42b4af3ba753be1b55fe8f897d8/src/data.js#L61) (data.js#61), and the data you want to store on that object is stored in a global jQuery cache.

However the `window` element does not have a `nodeType` property, so it goes down the route of *I'm a plain JS object*; which leads the data to be stored directly on the object itself (which, in the case of `window`, *may* be a bug with jQuery).

The choice of cache location (global or on the object) is made in [L39-45 in data.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ab409d14bc6db42b4af3ba753be1b55fe8f897d8/src/data.js#L39-45):

```
// We have to handle DOM nodes and JS objects differently because IE6-7
// can't GC object references properly across the DOM-JS boundary
isNode = elem.nodeType,

// Only DOM nodes need the global jQuery cache; JS object data is
// attached directly to the object so GC can occur automatically
cache = isNode ? jQuery.cache : elem,
```

In the case of normal DOM elements, the value is assigned a GUID in [data.js#61](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ab409d14bc6db42b4af3ba753be1b55fe8f897d8/src/data.js#L61):

```
elem[ internalKey ] = id = jQuery.deletedIds.pop() || jQuery.guid++;
```

But in the case of normal JS objects (and `window` in this case), the object is built in [68 - 74](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ab409d14bc6db42b4af3ba753be1b55fe8f897d8/src/data.js#L68-74):

```
cache[id] = {};

// Avoids exposing jQuery metadata on plain JS objects when the object
// is serialized using JSON.stringify
if (!isNode) {
    cache[id].toJSON = jQuery.noop;
}​
```

The weird value is `jQuery.expando`, which is defined in [data.js#14](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ab409d14bc6db42b4af3ba753be1b55fe8f897d8/src/data.js#L14), and is initialized to:

```
"jQuery" + ( jQuery.fn.jquery + Math.random() ).replace( /\D/g, "" )
```

(basically, "jQuery", followed by the jQuery version with "."'s removed (1800 in your case), and then a random number).

Comment: except I put some thing in the event.data, I did not use .data() in jQuery.

Comment: @huahua: Using jQuery's events is enough to generate this expando, as jQuery uses data behind the scenes for events (whether you use `event.data` or not).

Comment: When using a module bundler like Webpack or rollup, is there anyway to prevent this expando property being set on `Window` to keep everything local?

Answer (score 7):

looking at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js i found there's a place that's creating something like what we're seeing.

Around line 1522:

```
// Unique for each copy of jQuery on the page
// Non-digits removed to match rinlinejQuery
expando: "jQuery" + ( jQuery.fn.jquery + Math.random() ).replace( /\D/g, "" ),
```

Maybe that's being used in a way that causes the object to appear.

After looking into it some more im more convinced this is the answer.

have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/USAcv/

Also, for different versions of jQuery it looks a little different:

```
jQuery16406568800362638323  v1.6.4
jQuery18007779947370290756  v1.8.0
jQuery1820604904827339435   v1.8.2
```

you can see the version is at the first part of the numeric numbers.

I also found that there are places that `elem[ expando ]` is created.  if `elem` is `window` then this is it.

for example, on line 4770 of the jquery-latest.js it has

```
if ( (cache = elem[ expando ]) === cachedkey ) {
```

Comment: except I put some thing in the event.data, I did not use .data() in jQuery.

Comment: excellent answer. I do have a event stored in window[expando]