# In IE dynamic attribute jquery with some number and its value is added, why ??

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

```
<DIV id=3949 class=tempClass channel-name="Brand" sizcache="50" nodeIndex="1" jQuery1362033550328="46"></div>
```

What is [jQuery1362033550328="46"]? It is showing in IE only not firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150592/why-does-my-form-element-have-a-random-jquery-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1362033550328` is the unix timestamp which is equivalent to `Thu, 28 Feb 2013 06:52:00 GMT`

Mostly its appended along with ajax requests to avoid ajax cache problems